# Bundler finds the wrong version of ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, bundler, activesupport

I'm using OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite).  I'm trying to clone the [github repo](https://github.com/MacDownApp/macdown) for MacDown.  The instructions in the README say that after cloning one should do

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
bundle install
bundle exec pod install
```

I'm not a ruby programmer, so I had to install Bundler.  The first two steps ran fine, but when I tried to run `bundle install` I got the error

```
activesupport-5.0.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.2.2, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.0.0p481
```

So I tried `brew install ruby` and now I have

```
saul@miniMac ✓ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

However, `bundle install` gives me the same error message as before.  It's clear that it's finding the ruby at `/usr/bin/ruby` instead of the one at `/usr/local/bin/ruby`.  How do I correct this?

I thought that perhaps the problem was that I had installed bundler before upgrading ruby, neither `sudo gem uninstall bundler` nor `sudo gem uninstall bundle` has any effect, and I don't know what else to try.

Here is all the output, in case it's relevant:

```
saul@miniMac ✓ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
activesupport-5.0.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.2.2, which is incompatible with
the current version, ruby 2.0.0p481
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried `gem install bundler` again, but it didn't help.  I got the same error message.  Here's what I get from `bundle env`

```
saul@miniMac ✗ bundle env
Environment

    Bundler   1.13.6
    Rubygems  2.0.14
    Ruby      2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
    Git       2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)

Gemfile

    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'cocoapods', '0.39.0'

Gemfile.lock

<No /Users/saul/Projects/macdown/Gemfile.lock found>
```

EDIT 2:

```
saul@miniMac ✓ which -a bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
/usr/bin/bundle
```

Comment: What does `bundle env` show? Also, I would check the head of your bundle file to see what's been hard coded in the `#!` operator. https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4260

Comment: I think you just need to install Bundler for the homebrew version on Ruby. Does `gem install bundler` (again) fix it?

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r Thanks, but I don't understand how to "check the head of my bundle file."  I don't know anything about ruby.

Comment: What does `which -a bundle` show?

Comment: @matt Please see EDIT 2 above.

Comment: @saulspatz for completeness, could you also check `which -a ruby` and `which -a gem`? Maybe rubygems need to be installed separately from Homebrew?

Comment: @ma_il Similar to above.  For both, I see first the copy in `/usr/local/bin' and then the copy in '/usr/bin'.  If I just use `which` with the `-a`, in both cases I see the copy in '\usr\local\bin`

Comment: @saulspatz: interesting. I assume that `/usr/local/bin` precedes `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` environment variable? My time using MacOS is already a few years past, but my general recommendation would be to remove the Homebrew version of Ruby again and install `rbenv`([readme](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x)) instead.

Comment: @ma_il You're right about the path, of course.  I'll try out your advice, but I may not be able to get to it today.  Thanks.

Comment: @ma_il I've uninstalled the Homebrew ruby, installed `rbenv`, and installed ruby by means of `rbenv install 2.3.1`, but `bundle install` gives the same result as before, and `which -a ruby` only shows `/usr/bin/ruby`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @saulsplatz sounds like rbenv is not loaded properly. Did you start your console as a login shell?

Comment: @ma_il Yes I did.  I think I've got things royally messed up.  I'm going to try to back everything out and start over.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Just ran into this as well. Looks like the bash somehow caches the latest used binary path and just reuses this. Restarting the shell solved it for me.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your PATH may have an entry that points to your older version of Ruby and despite having a newer version (2.3.1) it gets to use the first ruby binary it finds in one of the entries it finds in your PATH, which happens to be the old version. You could try to add your latest Ruby path as the first entry of your PATH variable, but in case a sub-shell is run and the default PATH is loaded the path to your latest Ruby would be overwritten. That being said, I think the easiest would be to use rvm here to make sure your environment is all set up with the version you intend to use at any given time. RVM can manage multiple versions of ruby in the same system. Read more [about RVM here](https://rvm.io/).

Run **all** the following commands in the same terminal window:

1. Install rvm: *curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s  stable*
2. Add rvm binary to PATH: *export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"*
3. Install ruby version you need: *rvm install 2.3.1*
4. Configure the current shell to use a specific version of Ruby like so: *rvm use 2.3.1*
5. Run *bundle install* again